# Using .map() on an object doesn't get executed across shards

Tags: rethinkdb

I have an indexed sub-query which I'd like to run on an array of strings. Problem is, if I go:

```js
var things = ['i1', 'i2', 'i3', '...', 'i1000'];

r.expr(things).map(function(i) {
  return invokeIndexedSubQuery(i);
})
```

`.map()` iterates `things` sequentially and doesn't use the cluster's true power by running it in parallel across shards (slow).

I find it weird that creating a new table and inserting the array's items as table rows, makes `.map()` execution efficient as expected:

```js
r.table(things).map(function(i) {
  return invokeIndexedSubQuery(i);
}) // across shards -- fast
```

Isn't `.map()` mentioned in the documentation as a method which performed across shards? What can I do in order to use it directly on an object (such as array)?

v2.3.4

Answer (score 0):

RethinkDB distributes `map` commands over the input data. If your data is in a table, the `map` is distributed to each shard (which could be on another server if you have a sharded table). If your data is in an array, the `map` gets executed on the thread that contains your data.

The reason RethinkDB does this might be that it cannot tell if the overhead of copying the data to other threads or servers and aggregating the results is worth the effort, which in many cases it isn't.

You can sometimes optimize this behaviour, for example you could use `r.range` instead of `r.expr([...])` for sequential data, and if `f` performs an insert you can sometimes turn `x.map(f)` into `t.insert(x)` or if it performs a `get`, `t.getAll(r.args(X))`.

Comment: "The reason RethinkDB does this might be that it cannot tell if the overhead of copying the data to other threads or servers and aggregating the results is worth the effort, which in many cases it isn't." -- I guess it would be nice to have the ability to force it